# What does this Relational Algebra Statement Do? (converting to SQL query)

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database

I am trying to translate from Relational Algebra to SQL Query:

```
ρ(R1, ΠroomId((ΠguestIdσage<35Guest) Natural Join Reservation))
ρ(R2, ΠroomIdσprice≤100∨numberOfBeds>2Room)
R1 ∧ R2
```

I understand that it is renaming the output to R1, and R2 for the second part and then it performs *R1 AND R2*

However, my confusion is converting from the Relational Algebra to the Query

Can somebody help or provide some insight as to how this would be done?

Answer (score 0):

The first statement is `selecting` from relation `Guest` all the records where `age` is lower than `35`, `projecting` only the `guestId` column.

This resulting relation is then `naturally joined` with another table `Reservation`, `projecting` the result on the `roomId` and calling the result `R1`.

The second statement is `selecting` from relation Room all the rows that have `price` lower or equal than `100` or more than `2` beds, `projecting` the results with the `roomId`, calling this second result `R2`.

If I read this correctly, it's translation into SQL should be something like:

```
SELECT roomId AS R1
FROM (
    SELECT guestId 
    FROM Guest
    WHERE age < 35 
) AS YoungGuests NATURAL JOIN Reservation
WHERE roomId IN (
    SELECT roomId AS R2
    FROM Room
    WHERE price <= 100 OR numberOfBeds > 2
);
```

The idea is to select all the rooms reserved for guests younger than 35 that have at least 2 beds or a price lower than 100. [Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a7d301/1) a working example (with some dummy data).

Comment: Could you explain where the Union came from? Isn't the '^' meant to be an AND?

Comment: I did try this query - but this wasn't the right translation as it produced errors

Comment: @RandomMath Fixed, this version should work as you want.